# finding the django-registration username variable

Tags: django

Ok Here goes.

With django-registration i have created a  user with passwords etc. 
I have named the user Zoro. The registration was a success and it takes me to

"You are now registered. Activation email sent."

Email activation is turned off. So i go to login page and login. This is done under 127.0.0.1/accounts/login. The login.html template successfully extends the base.html template. And within the base.html template i have a tag {{ user }}, which i want to show the username at the top left.

When i login my urls are extended away from ^/accounts/login to ^/homepage. Know i dont know where the current username is stored, so i cant pass to {{ user }} the curent user's name in views. So {{ user }} is blank.

But.......If i go back to the login page, the current username is at the top left.

I am new, be gentle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different options to add the `{{ user }}` to your templates context:

a) add `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting. This will make a `{{ user }}` template variable available in all context's when rendering templates.

b) do it by hand and add a `user` variable to pass it to the context in your view. `user` can be retrieved from `request.user`

c) Make sure you are not overwrting `{{ user }}` somewhere.