# Add Django Variables in Email Template

Tags: django-registration, django-signals, user-object

I have a relatively simple objective: send email to Django admins when users register and activate their accounts that contain user information, like username, email, etc. I am using `django-registration` for handling the registration process. I then employ signals to send the emails. This process works just fine, but as soon as I try to inject the user, username or user's email into an email template I get in trouble.

Here is my `signal_connectors.py`:

```
from django.core.mail import mail_admins
from django.dispatch import receiver
from registration.signals import user_registered
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

@receiver(user_registered, dispatch_uid="common.signal_connectors.user_registered_handler")
def user_registered_handler(sender, **kwargs):

    print('user registration completed...')

    subject = 'registration notify'
    template = 'common/email.html'
    message = render_to_string(template, {'user': user})
    from_email = 'from@example.com'

    # send email to admins, if user has been registered
    mail_admins(subject, message, fail_silently=False, connection=None, html_message=None)

    print('sending email to administrators...')
```

The template is like so:

```
{{ user }} has registered at example.com
```

I have tried variations like `{{user}}`, `{{user.username}}`, `{{request.user.username}}`, etc. Also, in the `message` variable above, in `signals_connectors.py`, I have tried variations, with corresponding import statements.

I have also tried rendering templates with contexts set, and other variations that I have found on the web, eg:

[finding the django-registration username variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266000/finding-the-djang-registration-username-variable)

I keep getting something like this for an error:

```
global name 'user' is not defined
```

I think I have template context processing set up correctly, because I can use something like `{{ user.username }}` in another template and it works.

I have also tried correcting my import statements to include necessary objects, with no luck. I have tried most of what I can find on the web on this topic so I'm at a loss...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize this was so easy. Based on this post:

[Where should signal handlers live in a django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719038/where-should-signal-handlers-live-in-a-django-project)

I tried actually adding the user and request as arguments in the signal connector method and this worked:

```
. . .

@receiver(user_registered, dispatch_uid="common.signal_connectors.user_registered_handler")
def user_registered_handler(sender, user, request, **kwargs):

. . .
```

Then, I used this in email template:

{{ user }} has registered at example.com

I probably over-thought this one but I am surprised no one stepped up and was able to help with this...